# MSAGL: GraphViewerGdi: How to programmatically reset the zoom (or programmatically press the Home button to reset it)?

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, msagl

I want to right click on a node to zoom into that node, then right click again to completely reset the zoom and pan to its starting state. Furthermore, I may in future wish to hide the viewer's built-in toolbar and perform the zoom-out with a hotkey. So "just press the existing Home button" is not a solution for my use case.

I already have the zoom-in working using `ShowBBox()`.

I cannot find a way to programmatically zoom out exactly like the Home button would do.

- The viewer has no `ResetZoom()`, `HomeButtonPressed()`, or any such method that I can find.
- Setting `.ZoomF` back to 1.0 is not sufficient because it does not simultaneous center the panning (and `Pan(0,0)` does not center the pan either.)
- `gvMain.ShowBBox(gvMain.Graph.BoundingBox)` does not work (the zoom changes very slightly, but not to a fully reset state akin to the Home button.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the [home button is doing](https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/bc1ebccc49e9e4560022a08fcc8c15aa801f24f2/GraphLayout/tools/GraphViewerGDI/GViewer.cs#L1792) is setting the `Transform` to null. So you can also do the same to reset the transform:

```
//Press home button:
gViewer1.Transform = null;
gViewer1.Invalidate();
```

Just in case that someone is interested to programmatically invoke the other buttons' operations, here are the methods:

- ZoomInPressed()
- ZoomOutPressed()
- BackwardButtonPressed()
- ForwardButtonPressed()
- SaveButtonPressed()
- PrintButtonPressed()
- OpenButtonPressed()
- UndoButtonPressed()
- RedoButtonPressed()
- LayoutSettingsIsClicked()